# Outlook 2016: Narrow results when searching messages with inline images in body

Tags: images, search, microsoft-outlook-2016, email-client

I was wondering if there's a way to search through messages that have inline images embedded because I need to gather images about a certain subject. I have no way to search using only text because these cases I need to research are in emails not categorized, they come from different sources, the subjects in the email are not standardized, the messages are from a wide range of dates, etc.

The best way I think that can help me is to search for messages with inline images and look at the images I need manually. To accomplish this I found [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_windows8-mso_2010/are-there-any-way-to-search-for-e-mails-with/62330093-fc2a-4edf-a4c2-5c07592b410d) very helpful. It states that the keyword `body:` alongside the extension `jpg` will retrieve messages with inline images.

That's helpful!

But I also got results that include images I don't want to get, I'm talking about corporative signatures in emails footer that everyone in the company sends...

For my particular problem I know I need to visually search for the images I need BUT: ***is there a way to narrow this search for example by the size of these inline images?***

That way I could search for a larger size than the little signature image. I'm not searching for messages using just size because of the attachments. Is there a better way to accomplish such a task?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no option to realize this, but you can post your idea to Outlook UserVoice: https://outlook.uservoice.com/

Comment: @Perry I suspected there was no way but people's great internet knowledge may be of help I thought, maybe someone would know something... Thanks for your suggestion, I've followed it. I titled the idea: [Searching tools for inline images in email body](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/38176489-searching-tools-for-inline-images-in-email-body) Hopefully, it will be taken into consideration in some... ages. Maybe for Outlook 2089